# Is it possible to set image or button at the center of navigationbar in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Is it possible to set image or button at the center of navigationbar in iphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, have a look at the [UINavigationItem's titleView property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006933-CH3-SW2). In my application I added a UIView with a UILabel and UIImageView, for instance.